# If conditional statement not working in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Check for the NAN values for 2 columns, if both the columns are blank so need to update the col3 with "All Blanks"

I have tried working with it but its not working.

Input Data:

```
S.no      col1          col2          col3
 1.
 2.    9786543628      AZ256hy         
 3.                               
 4.    9784533930      AZ256hc         
 5.    9778934593      AZ256py
```

**Code i have been using**

```
df['col3']=df.apply(lambda x:'All Blanks' if (x['col1'] == " ") and (x['col2'] == " "))
print(df['col3'])
```

But it's Not working.

Please Suggest.

Comment: "But it's Not working." is not an adequate description of the problem. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` here is not recommended, because it is loops under the hoods and always try avoit it if exist some vectorized alternatives. So use:

Missing values are not spaces (or empty strings), so for test use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and for new column [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col3']=np.where(df['col1'].isna() & df['col2'].isna(), 'All Blanks' , df['col3'])
```

Or test columns selected by list with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for all `True`s per rows:

```
df['col3']=np.where(df[['col1', 'col2']].isna().all(axis=1), 'All Blanks' , df['col3'])
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the Answer, But what in the case where we dont have to use else statement value, Actually having the values already stored in the col 3, Only looking to update the rows where col1 and col2 are blanks. in rest of the rows let the value as it is.

Comment: @NKJ - then change `'All Blanks' , '')` to `'All Blanks' , df['col3'])`

Comment: @NKJ - If matching then update, else original column values

Answer (score 1):

You can also use boolean mask, `assign()` method and `fillna()` method:

```
mask=(df['col1'].isna()) & (df['col2'].isna())


df=df.assign(col3=df.loc[mask]['col3'].fillna('All Blanks'))
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output

Comment: Not working, As when checking the column in dataframe It has NaN in place of blank values, I have also tried using this mask=(df['col1'] == 'NaN') & (df['col2'] == 'NaN'),

Comment: Updated my answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @jezrael Sir I know that what you are trying to say...but Sir  you already gived numpy's `where()` method as an answer so that's why I gived this alternate solution...Btw I mentioned it in the answer that numpy's `where()` method is more efficient  **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas - Thanks for the Answer, But what in the case where we dont have to use else statement, Actually having some values already stored in the col 3, Only looking to update the rows where col1 and col2 are blanks. in rest of the rows let the value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have empty strings (instead of NaN) and want to use `apply` across multiple columns you should pass the argument `axis=1`, as in:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})

df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["a"] + x["b"], axis=1)

print(df)
```